# Could you tell me some advise Oracle Error?

Tags: oracle

Sorry, I don't well English.

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation(
    tno NUMBER,
    sno NUMBER,
    cno NUMBER,
    seat_no NUMBER,
    Res_Date DATE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_RES_TNO FOREIGN KEY (tno) REFERENCES Theater(tno),
    CONSTRAINT FK_RES_SNO FOREIGN KEY (sno) REFERENCES Screen(sno),
    CONSTRAINT FK_RES_CNO FOREIGN KEY (cno) REFERENCES T_Customer(cno),
    CONSTRAINT PK_RESERVATION PRIMARY KEY (tno,sno,cno)
    --CONSTRAINT RES_UNIQUE UNIQUE (cno)
);
```

I Write Oracle Table.
But throw me Error "ORA-02270"
I don't know come to me this message.

Could you tell me some advise?

Comment: From https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02270.php it seems one of those foreign keys are referring to a table that doesn't have primary key.  Please check whether or not those other tables have primary keys.

Comment: Thank you. i resolve problem.

ref_table PK have 2 index. thank you

Comment: Please don't feel that you need to apologize for your English. What you wrote was understood by everyone. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you so mach. i receive power to you.

Answer (score 0):

There would be multiple reasons for having this error,

1. You may have same primary key already, which might be disabled
2. Composite primary key in the table may not provide you the unique (this error many happen only when the table is ALTERED, since its new table, this logical check can be ignored)